# LNK 4099 with a conan package in cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, glfw, conan

I have a Cmake for windows to be compiled with visual studio. For some dependencies (glfw, glm, assimp) I use conan.

Here the conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
assimp/5.2.2
glfw/3.3.7
glm/0.9.9.8

[generators]
cmake_find_package
```

and here the main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.3)

project(Reskinner)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)     
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /Z7")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/Main.cpp)

#   Retrieve conan.cmake
if (NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
    message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
    file(DOWNLOAD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/master/conan.cmake" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
endif ()

include("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")

conan_cmake_run(CONANFILE "conanfile.txt" BASIC_SETUP UPDATE BUILD missing)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
find_package(glm REQUIRED)
find_package(assimp REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(Libraries/include/glad)
add_subdirectory(Libraries/include/stb)
add_subdirectory(Libraries/include/imgui)
add_subdirectory(Libraries/include/FileBrowser)
add_subdirectory(src)

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY
        "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/../Shaders")
        
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY
        "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/../Animations")

function(install_file_to_bin dir_name file_name)
    file(INSTALL "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${dir_name}/${file_name}" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/../${dir_name}")
endfunction()

install_file_to_bin(Shaders 1.model_loading.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders 1.model_loading.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders 4.1.fshader.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders 4.1.vshader.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders animated_model_loading.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders animated_model_loading.gs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders animated_model_loading.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders bb.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders bb.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders default.frag)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders default.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders default.geom)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders default.vert)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders default.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders floor.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders floor.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders framebuffer.frag)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders framebuffer.vert)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders grey_model.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders grey_model.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders hover.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders hover.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders influence_of_single_bone.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders influence_of_single_bone.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders mouse_shader.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders mouse_shader.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders normal_visualizer.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders normal_visualizer.gs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders normal_visualizer.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders no_lighting_shader.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders no_lighting_shader.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders num_bones_visualization.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders num_bones_visualization.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders screen_shader.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders screen_shader.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders selected.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders selected.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders smooth_lighting_shader.fs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders smooth_lighting_shader.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders wireframe.vs)
install_file_to_bin(Shaders wireframe.fs)

install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Capoeira")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Flair")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Silly Dancing")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Capoeira/Capoeira.dae")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Capoeira/textures")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Capoeira/textures/FitnessGrandma_diffuse.jpg")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Capoeira/textures/FitnessGrandma_FaceAnimMap.png")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Capoeira/textures/FitnessGrandma_normal.jpg")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Capoeira/textures/FitnessGrandma_spec.jpg")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Flair/Flair.dae")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Flair/textures")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Flair/textures/FitnessGrandma_diffuse.jpg")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Flair/textures/FitnessGrandma_FaceAnimMap.png")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Flair/textures/FitnessGrandma_normal.jpg")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Flair/textures/FitnessGrandma_spec.jpg")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Silly Dancing/Silly Dancing.dae")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Silly Dancing/textures")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Silly Dancing/textures/FitnessGrandma_diffuse.jpg")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Silly Dancing/textures/FitnessGrandma_FaceAnimMap.png")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Silly Dancing/textures/FitnessGrandma_normal.jpg")
install_file_to_bin(Animations "Nonna/Silly Dancing/textures/FitnessGrandma_spec.jpg")

set(CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE 1)
set(CMAKE_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE 1)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE)

include_directories(
    ${glfw3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${glm_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${assimp_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    Libraries/include
    src
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    glad
    glfw::glfw
    glm::glm 
    stb
    assimp::assimp
    imgui
    FileBrowser
    Engine 
)

target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC /W4 /w44265 /w44061 /w44062 /permissive- /Wv:18 /wd4201 /w44800)
```

if I go to the build dir and run:

```
cmake -S .. (which is the root dir) -B . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

I get errors with assimp trying to link release build stuffs with debug stuffs.
Since I don't care about building it in Debug or Release I run this:

```
cmake -S .. (which is the root dir) -B . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

but now I get this:

```
glfw3.lib(context.obj) : warning LNK4099: can't find the PDB 'glfw3.pdb' with 'glfw3.lib(context.obj)' or in 'C:\
Users\franc\Desktop\Mesh Loader\MeshLoader\build\Debug\glfw3.pdb'; object linked withoud debug info [C:\Us
ers\franc\Desktop\Mesh Loader\MeshLoader\build\Reskinner.vcxproj]
```

Now since glfw is managed by conan i don't understand why this doesn't work. Moreover, as you can see in the CMakeLists.txt I use the /Z7 flag for debug that should fix this problem as i read on other questions here but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: .pdb files are not packaged in Conan Center, if you need them, you need to build those packages from source. /Z7 is the correct approach if you don't want .pdb files.

Comment: But if /Z7 is the correct approach why it's not working? Am I missing something or doing something wrong?